# Oracle SQL - check constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, check-constraints

This check constraint isn't working for me:

```
ALTER TABLE tab1
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK1 CHECK 
(col1 in ('val1','val2','val3','val4') and (col2='0' or col2 IS NULL))
ENABLE;
```

What I need is if col1 contains any of the mentioned 4 values, then col2 has to be '0' or 'NULL'.

Comment: what's not working?

Comment: is the data type of `col2` non-numeric? If so, that should contain some whitespaces, since the constraint seems to be flawless for an integer value(except for redundant quotes wrapping up zero).

Comment: Btw,  make sure `col1` also shouldn't contain whitespaces for those values('val1','val2'...)

Comment: col2 is "number" datatype and col1 is varchar with about 14 different values of which oly 4 I am concerned of for this particular constraint

Comment: select * from tab1 where (col1 in ('val1','val2','val3','val4') and (TAX_AMOUNT!='0' and TAX_AMOUNT IS NOT NULL)); - This returns 0 records, so theres no rows violating the constraint I am trying to add right?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `col1` is nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE tab1
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK1 CHECK 
(col1 not in ('val1','val2','val3','val4') or (col1 is not null and (col2='0' or col2 IS NULL)))
ENABLE;
```

If it's not nullable then you can take out the `col1 is not null` but it's not going to be too important.

The constraint now means:
If `col1` isn't in those values then it's fine.
But if it is, then the other side of the condition must be met.

Comment: My constraint should check col2 is either '0' or 'NULL' if col1 contains any of the 4 values. Reverse doesn't hold true, Values other then these 4 in col1 can also contain 0 in col2

Comment: That’s exactly what the code I’ve shared will do, try it with your test cases

Answer (score 1):

You can write this as:

```
ALTER TABLE tab1
    ADD CONSTRAINT CHK1 
        CHECK (col1 NOT IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4') OR
               col2 <> '0'
              )
```

This can be equivalently written as:

```
    CHECK (NOT (col1 IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4') AND
                col2 <> '0'
               )
          )
```

These both allow values other than the four specified values for `col1` with no restriction on `col2`.

Comment: My constraint should check col2 is either '0' or 'NULL' if col1 contains any of the 4 values. Reverse doesn't hold true, Values other then these 4 in col1 can also contain 0 in col2

Comment: @sp123 . . . These should guarantee that you never have the four values in `col1` with anything other than `'0'` or `NULL` in `col2`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE tab1 ADD CONSTRAINT CHK1 
    CHECK (col1 NOT IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4') OR col2 = '0')
ENABLE;
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=485a50d592b78b306f5aa42cac393862)

Comment: My constraint should check col2 is either '0' or 'NULL' if col1 contains any of the 4 values. Reverse doesn't hold true, Values other then these 4 in col1 can also contain 0 in col2

Comment: I think you did not try it. See fiddle with different value than listed and 0 in col2. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=908ffc9e77dba2fe8f826aeb96b19746

Answer (score 0):

I think your current should work properly as `col2` has numeric data type, except quotes wrapping up zero (`'0'`) is redundant within the constraint, and be aware that the values of `col1` listed within the constraint are to be inserted into the table without whitespaces. So, you might use the current check constraint, even briefly with a slight change through use of `NVL()` function as below :

```
ALTER TABLE tab1
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK1 
CHECK(col1 IN ('val1','val2','val3','val4') AND NVL(col2,0)=0)
ENABLE;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1c6336daf396aac168946b6a0f37adff)</kbd>